# MongoDB document setup and aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and while preparing data to be consumed I got into Aggregation... what a powerful little thing this database has! I got really excited and started to test some things :)

I'm saving time entries for a companyId and employeeId ... that can have many entries... those are normally sorted by date, but one date can have several entries (multiple registrations in the same day)

I'm trying to come up with a good schema so I could easily get my data exactly how I need and as a newbie, I would rather ask for guidance and check if I'm in the right path

my output should be as

```
[{
    "company": "474A5D39-C87F-440C-BE99-D441371BF88C",
    "employee": "BA75621E-5D46-4487-8C9F-C0CE0B2A7DE2",
    "name": "Bruno Alexandre":
    "registrations": [{
        "id": 1448364,
        "spanned": false,
        "spannedDay": 0,
        "date": "2019-01-17",
        "timeStart": "09:00:00",
        "timeEnd": "12:00:00",
        "amount": {
            "days": 0.4,
            "hours": 2,
            "km": null,
            "unit": "days and hours",
            "normHours": 5
        },
        "dateDetails": {
            "week": 3,
            "weekDay": 4,
            "weekDayEnglish": "Thursday",
            "holiday": false
        },
        "jobCode": {
            "id": null,
            "isPayroll": true,
            "isFlex": false
        },
        "payroll": {
            "guid": null
        },
        "type": "Sick",
        "subType": "Sick",
        "status": "APP",
        "reason": "IS",
        "group": "LeaveAndAbsence",
        "note": null,
        "createdTimeStamp": "2019-01-17T15:53:55.423Z"
  }, /* more date entries */ ]
}, /* other employees */ ]
```

what is the best way to add the data into a collection?

**Is it more efficient** if I create a document **per company/employee** and add all registration entries inside that document (it could get really big as time passes)... or is it better to have one document **per company/employee/date** and add all daily events in that document instead?

regarding aggregation, I'm still new to all this, but I'm imagining I could simply call

```
RegistrationsModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            date: { $gte: new Date('2019-01-01'), $lte: new Date('2019-01-31') },
            company: '474A5D39-C87F-440C-BE99-D441371BF88C'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$employee',
            name: { '$first': '$name' }
        }
    },
    {
        // ... get all registrations as an Array ...
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            'registrations.date': -1
        }
    }
]);
```

P.S. I'm taken the [Aggregation course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mongodb-aggregation-framework) to start familiarized with all of it

Comment: Remember the maximum document size is 16 megabytes https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it more efficient if I create a document per company/employee and
>   add all registration entries inside that document (it could get really
>   big as time passes)... or is it better to have one document per
>   company/employee/date and add all daily events in that document
>   instead?

From what I understand of document oriented databases, I would say the aim is to have all the data you need, in a specific context, grouped inside one document.
So what you need to do is identify what data you're going to need (getting close to the features you want to implement) and build your data structure according to that. Be sure to identify future features, cause the more you prepare your data structure to it, the less it will be tricky to scale your database to your needs.

Your aggregation query looks ok !